# google vm instances does not seem to be on correct region

Tags: ip, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, geolocation

I created one google vm machine engine instance in eu-west1-b region. In GCP Console seems to be in eu-west1-b region. However when I try to gelocate my ip's they seem to be in somewhere in China.
The IP of the server is: 35.241.151.245

I read a similar case in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829340/my-google-app-instances-does-not-seem-to-be-on-correct-region#

But, i dont see a solution

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to add the actual IP address, if you wish to understand which service provider advertises it.

Comment: ok, added the ip of the server....thank you

Answer (score 1):

That IP is announced by [AS15169 which is a part of  Google Cloud](https://bgp.he.net/ip/35.241.151.245#_whois).

Geolocation of IP addresses is unreliable. Sometimes the correct city, sometimes the incorrect continent.

- Geo IP databases are somewhat incomplete and out of date
- IPv4 address space is fragmented and resold
- Private transit networks take traffic off the Internet and appear somewhere far away

Think about why you care where a host is on the planet.

For performance, start measuring application performance. Western Europe to China through the great firewall will perform poorly. Try different regions until you find a close one by network latency.

Data sovereignty, compliance, and other political concerns may require determining where it physically is. Ask your compliance person whether the API telling you which region is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of external public IP addresses in Google Cloud: Global and Regional.

If you are using a Regional IP address then you know what region it is in by selecting the region when you create it. Regional IP addresses can only be used in the same region.

All Google IP addresses are owned by Google and typically point to one of Google's business addresses which does not indicate the physical location.

Do not rely upon or trust geolocation services for IP addresses. Today, IP addresses are logical entities (I am oversimplifying) and can be assigned to different data centers, in some cases to multiple data centers at the same time (IP ANYCAST). They can also be reassigned (Software Defined Networks) with an API call.